# What does the variable name "lsSQL" mean?

Tags: .net, variable-names

I've noticed in a [recent article](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/A-Vestigial-Query.aspx) on TDWTF that someone was using the variable name `lsSQL` . I have also noticed similar variable names in a legacy application I am working on and in [other places around the web](http://www.google.com/search?q=lssql), but I have never found out what the `ls` prefix stands for.

What does `ls` mean? What kind of notation is that?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Am I the only one that first read this as "IsSQL"?  Not a great Hungarian letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that this is a usage of Hungarian notation is Basic-like language (i.e. without strong typing). Here I would expect `l` to denote something like "local variable" as opposite to "argument" or "global variable", and `s` to denote type i.e. string here.

Comment: That's what i thought, but it felt strange to see Hungarian notation in a PHP application...

Comment: Well, Hungarian notation is not bound only to some languages. It might be used in almost any imperative language. And in my opinion Hungarian notation is not always evil. I think that the best article on this top is written by Joel http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Answer (score 2):

If my VB Naming Convention Fu serves me right, I believe the `ls` prefix stands for Local String (and then the SQL mearly indicates that it's the SQL Statement).

As a comparison reference in those situations, I would expect there to also be a variable prefixed with `lcon` for Local Connection.